# Get the list of goals for a Analytics View (profile)

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Working with Google Analytics Core Reporting API to to query goal conversion data, I can obtain the total goal conversions if I query the API with the following parameter:

```
 $metrics    = 'ga:goal1Completions,ga:goal2Completions,ga:goal3Completions',
   [
        'dimensions'    => 'ga:date',
        'output'        => 'dataTable'
    ]
```

[image]

The problem is that I do not know how many goals are registered for each View (Profile), in this example, the target 3 does not exist.

How can I list the available goals for a particular View (Profile)?

Comment: Can you try to rephrase this a bit ? I do not quite understand what you are asking.

Comment: in analytics you can create N goals conversion, ok? i want get goals  created, but i don't know how many goals conversion have created. in this example, the metric `ga:goal3Completions` don't exists for customer 1 but for customer 2 exists!

Comment: I would rephrase the question like this "How do I list the goals for a particular view (profile)?" Answer: use the Management API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the [`goals.list` method](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/goals/list) from the Google Analytics Management API.

```
/**
 * Example #1:
 * Requests goals for a single view (profile).
 */
try {
  $goals = $analytics->management_goals->listManagementGoals($ACCOUNT_ID,
      $PROPERTY_ID,
      $VIEW_ID);

} catch (apiServiceException $e) {
  print 'There was an Analytics API service error '
      . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();

} catch (apiException $e) {
  print 'There was a general API error '
      . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Also goals are a [templatized deimension/metric](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/metadata/v3/devguide#templatized), which should let you know at least the minimum and maximum values if you are to query the [Google Analytics Metadata API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/metadata/v3/).